# What happens to tailed beast if jinchuriki dies?

Tags: naruto

As the title says, what happens to the tailed beast when jinchuriki dies by any reasons whether of old age or killed by enemies. Does it come out of jinchuriki alive or get reborn? What had happened to jinchuriki of three tails that it was the only bijuu that didn't have a jinchuriki in Naruto shippuden.

Comment: @Ero Sennin I couldnt find that. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the jinchuriki dies, the tailed beast gets "reborn", sort of.
It is not well explained in the series, however, it is mentioned (Raikage vs Naruto & Bee) that should the jinchuriki die, the tailed beast would be resurrected.

From the [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Tailed_Beast):

> Because the tailed beasts are pure chakra, they cannot actually be killed; if they or their jinchūriki die, their chakra will re-coalesce in time.
>   This is also mentioned when Minato seals the Kyuubi, see chapter 503, pages 14 and 17.

As for Sanbi's jinchuriki: May contain spoilers: (As I did read the manga to the end, but I've yet to catch onto the anime)

> We know of two jinchuriki that Sanbi had. The first being Yagura, being resurrected by Obito during the war. The second is Rin, which, after her capture, was forced to become Sanbi's jinchuriki, and it was planned to send her back to Konoha where Sanbi would break loose. (Since Rin died, and Sanbi didn't, it further proves what I said earlier, the bijuu comes back)

Comment: I wonder what will happen after Naruto dies. How will people maintain the peace? Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Reading 3rd tail Beast jinchuriki--->

When a tailed Beast is extracted from a jinchuriki,the jinchuriki dies as Gaara died when ONE Tailed Beast was extracted from him.It happened with Kusina and Naruto almost died while fighting with Madara.So Three Tailed Beast jinchuriki might have died as well.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question posed.

Comment: the answer is regarding 2nd part of that question,not the 1st part..